# How do I connect and execute validate method from Struts using regular HTML

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, struts2

I am trying to create a login form using Struts 2. For that I have created one JSP page below

```jsp
<form method="post" id="frmLogin" action="login" onSubmit="return loginValidation()">

    <table class="tblLogin">
        <tr><th colspan="2">Log in</th></tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="labels">Username:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtUsername" maxlength="10"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="labels">Password:</td>
            <td><input type="password" id="txtPassword" maxlength="16"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                <input type="image" class="loginButton" src="design/images/btn3.png" value="Log in">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

In the page I have validated the page using JavaScript. As well as I have created the action class with getters and setters and one execute method which returns `SUCCESS`.

While I searched internet, it is found that all examples are using Struts tags.

How do I connect and execute validate method from Struts using regular HTML. Otherwise what is the way to validate and submit the form using Struts 2.

Right now my problem is even I have given wrong username and password form submission happens.

Comment: @ Aleksandr M How do I validate and redirect to the success page using the above login form?

Comment: Are you talking about server or client -side validation?

Answer (score 2):

For **server side** validation:

You have to extend `ActionSupport` in your action class. Then, override the `validate()` method. Here's an example:

```
@Override
    public void validate() {
       if (this.username == null || this.username.isEmpty()) {
            addFieldError("username", "Username is required");
        }
       if (this.password == null || this.password.isEmpty()) {
            addFieldError("password", "Password is required");
        }
    }
```

If that worked out for you, you can add more statements on `validate()` method

Also, you can use `ActionSuport` `getText()` method to fetch an String containing the error message you want to show:

```
@Override
        public void validate() {
           if (this.username == null) {
                addFieldError("username", getText("err_username_req"));
            }
           ..... // same for password and other statements

        }
```

All you have to do is include `err_username_req` as a property in your struts2 resources files (just inside the one where you want to keep your strings, for example, for validation errors and stuff) and you'll be good to go :) .

Answer (score 0):

In the regular HTML you are missing some Struts2 features such as `xhtml` theme. This theme allows to display action errors along with input fields. To validate input fields you need to pass the values as parameters to the action. The action instance is created when you submit the form. Better if you bind the fields to the action attributes using the same name.

By default parameters not only consolidated in the action context but also populated the action instance. Make sure your action class extends `ActionSupport` because it's required for the `validation()` method to be invoked and has context for validation errors.

Use `defaultStack` of interceptors that include [`validation` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/validation-interceptor.html) and [`workflow` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/default-workflow-interceptor.html). The last one prevents the action to execute if the action has validation errors.

```html
<form method="post" id="frmLogin" action="login" onSubmit="return loginValidation()">

    <table class="tblLogin">
        <tr><th colspan="2">Log in</th></tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="labels">Username:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtUsername" name="username" maxlength="10"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="labels">Password:</td>
            <td><input type="password" id="txtPassword" name="password" maxlength="16"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                <input type="image" class="loginButton" src="design/images/btn3.png" value="Log in">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```